# Reading Data with InflaterInputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I am doing something like

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("test.dat", true);  //appending=true
Deflater d = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
DataOutputStream outFile = new DataOutputStream(new DeflatorOutputStream(fout, d));
```

to open a file for writing data, in a compressed format.  I write my data to the file:

```
void writeObject(MyObject o) {
outFile.writeLong(o.getDate().getTime());
outFile.writeChar(o.getValue1());
outFile.writeDouble(o.getValue2());
outFile.writeInt(o.getValue3());
```

Occasionally i flush the file, and close it.

and i read the data in:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test.dat");
DataInputStream inFile = new DataInputStream(new InflaterInputStream(fin));
try {    
 while(true) {
   long a = inFile.readLong();
   char b = inFile.readChar();
   double c = inFile.readDouble();
   int d = inFile.readInt()
   MyObject m = new MyObject(a,b,c,d);
   System.out.println(m.toString());
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

now when i write a bunch of MyObjects to the file, then flush() and close() the file.  then try and read them in, it works as expected.

however, if i write say 50 MyObjects to the file, flush(), close(), then reopen the file, then write 100 more MyObjects to it, I see the filesize grow on the disk as expected, but when i try and read, I am forever only able to read the first 50 objects (from the first open/close) once it gets to the end of them, i get:

```
java.io.DataInputStream.readFully
java.io.DataInputStream.readLong
```

On the read.  I dont know why this is happening.  if i remove the DeflatoerOutputStream/InflaterInputStream from the DataOutputStream/DataInputStream this works (all be it uncompressed) without issues.  what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance -

Comment: I *suspect* that the Deflater/Inflater streams don't really support appending. It looks like the reading stream just has indexes/references to the first set of objects in the file, and the second set are not identified at all.

Comment: @user1772250: What you are doing is the equivalent of taking two ZIP files and appending one file to the other.  Would you expect this to work?

Comment: so if i truly want to append i should open the file, read the contents into a buffer, then flush the buffer to a new file and append any data?  that was the workaround i thought might work, but wanted to be sure i wasnt doing something wrong somewhere else.  thanks